# Is there a graph parameter to request no cache?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, caching

The problem is when my Android app creates an #tagged event on facebook, it is not visible within the app for several minutes. However if i look in a fresh browser window i can see it. This must be down to it getting cached somewhere.

Here is my url construct for a straight HTTP get:

```
dataprov.setUrl("https://graph.facebook.com/search?type=event&q=MyAppName&limit=100&since=now&until=next%20year&fields=venue,location,attending,name,description,start_time,end_time,owner&&access_token="
                + ParseFacebookUtils.getSession().getAccessToken());
```

I need a parameter such as cache=false or something, but cannot find anything in docs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Facebook caches all calls to the API so that it doesn't use valuable resources trying to get the same information back several times. Facebook doesn't let you turn off the caching on your end - you just have to wait until Facebook updates its own cache. If developers had the option to turn off caching, everyone would probably do so, and bring Facebook's services to a grinding halt!

There is no solution for this - you will just have to wait it out. Usually, the cache is updated instantly.